Does the excel "LET" function perform lazy evaluation - are unused name value pairs actually evaluated
Suppose you have the following formula:
LAMBDA(returnVar_,
LET(
  let_var1, XLOOKUP(...),
  let_var2, XLOOKUP(...),
  delta, let_var1 - letvar2,
  SWITCH(returnVar_,
         "let_var1", let_var1,
         "let_var2", let_var2,
         "delta", let_var1 - letvar2))("let_var1")

Does excel evaluate "let_var2" and "delta" in such a scenario or is frugal/efficient to only evaluate "let_var1", "let_var2" or "delta" as needed?
I know based on the below microsoft reference that "let" is efficient to not evaluate items more than once if not needed. However I cannot find information on whether it evaluate it at least once in all cases:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

It's not about LET, it's about SWITCH. It will evaluate all its arguments.

Appears so: something like =LET(a,1,b,2,c,MMULT(RANDARRAY(1000,1000),RANDARRAY(1000,1000)),a+b) takes forever to calculate even though c is not actually used.

It may also depend on whether _returnVar is a scalar or an array. The IF function behaves differently for scalars and vectors, so perhaps SWITCH does too. As @GSerg says: break it down to just the SWITCH function and test its behaviour.

@GSerg does switch evaluate all or stop once it finds first match? _returnVar is indeed a scalar string

Thanks @GSerg, @BigBen, @DS_London. All of your comments point me in the right direction to test the behaviour.
I used the comments to make some tests of let, switch and if functions with the MMULT calculation/data generation and the behaviour is as follows based on the observed performance:
Support functions:
fn_MMULTData =LAMBDA(n,MMULT(RANDARRAY(n, n), RANDARRAY(n, n)))

testLet = LAMBDA(_returnVar,LET(aPlusb, 1 + 1, c, fn_MMULTData(1000), aPlusb))

testSwitch = LAMBDA(_returnVar,SWITCH(_returnVar, "aPlusb", 2, "c", fn_MMULTData(1000)))

testIF = LAMBDA(_returnVar,IF(_returnVar = "aPlusb", 2, fn_MMULTData(1000)))

The order of statements did not matter, nor did wrapping things in a helper LAMBDA except for the IF statement. Its performance didn't degrade due to evaluation of fn_MMULTData(1000) when it matched the condition. Maybe someone has a connection at Microsoft.
Edit 1:
CHOOSE seems combined with switch might be an elegant way of achieving the desired:
=LET(_returnVar, "1Plus1",
_returnVarIdx, SWITCH(_returnVar, "1plus1", 1, 2),
CHOOSE(_returnVarIdx, 1+1, fn_MMULTData(1000)))

Edit 2:
CHOOSE works also irrespective of order of evaluation
=LET(_returnVar, "1Plus1",
_returnVarIdx, SWITCH(_returnVar, "1plus1", 2, 1),
CHOOSE(_returnVarIdx, fn_MMULTData(1000), 1+1))

